# Count number of occurences in Dataframe per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe whereby all numbers are userID:

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

How do I count the number of occurrences for each columns, sum it up based on the same values and displays in the following format in a new dataframe?

| UserID | Occurences |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

Thank you.

Comment: Please include an example of your code.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can `stack` then `value_counts`

```py
out = (df.stack().value_counts()
       .to_frame('Occurences')
       .rename_axis('UserID')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   UserID  Occurences
0       1           2
1       2           2
2       3           2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.melt(value_name='UserID').groupby('UserID').size().reset_index(name='Occurences')
print (df)
   UserID  Occurences
0       1           2
1       2           2
2       3           2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pd.Series.value` counts method may be used to count the instances of each `userID` in the columns "from" and "to," and `pd.concat` can be used to combine the results. At the end create a dataframe from the resulting series using the pd.DataFrame.reset index method:

```py
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'from': [1, 1, 2], 'to': [3, 2, 3]})

occur = pd.concat([df['from'].value_counts(), df['to'].value_counts()])
result_df = occur.reset_index()
result_df.columns = ['UserID', 'occur']
result_df = result_df.groupby(['UserID'])['occur'].sum().reset_index()

   UserID         Occur
0       1           2
1       2           2
2       3           2
```